# If text in string, use other text in string to set a new string - Batch File

Tags: windows, batch-file

So, in my batch file, if I want to have an input such as

```
set /p command="Enter command here: "
```

And I want to make a command that sets a name, so

```
if /i "%command%" =="name Bob"
```

I want to first see if it contains the command *name* and then if it does, use the input after that to set the name, such as

```
set /p command="Enter command here: "
if /i "%command%" =="name Bob" goto :nameset (Line I'm having trouble with)
:nameset
set name=%nameinput%
```

I want the %nameinput% string to equal Bob, the value given when trying to run the name command. Thank you for the help.

Comment: In your example, if you use a `for /F "tokens=1,2" %%a in ("%command%") do ...`, then `%%a` is `name` and `%%b` is `Bob`, so just use the `%%a` part in the `if`, and the `%%b` part in the `set`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `for /f` to split your command into first word and rest.
if the first word (%%a) equals your command, set the variable to `%%b` (the rest). Or use `"tokens=1,2"` to set to the second word (ignoring the (possibly) following word(s)):

```
set /p command="Enter command here: "
for /f "tokens=1,*" %%a in ("%command%") do (
  if /i "%%a" == "name" set "%%a=%%b"
)
echo %name%
```